# Rendering fields from separate apps in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have my main app, and a tags app, I have added the tags to my blogpost model and have made sure I have added them in the back end. My problem is getting them to render.

My current code:

**MODEL**

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='blog_posts', blank=True)


class Tag(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.label

class TaggedItem(models.Model):

    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

**VIEW**

```
def Blog(request):
    posts =  BlogPost.objects.filter(date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-date')
    blog_paginator = Paginator(posts, per_page=4)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page = blog_paginator.get_page(page_number)

    tags = []
    for post in posts:
        post_tags = post.tags.all()
        tags.extend(post_tags)

    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'tags': tags,
        'page': page,
        
    }

    return render(request, 'mhpapp/blog.html', context)
```

**HTML**

```
{% for post in page.object_list %} 
            {% if post.published %}
                    
                    <span>
                        {% for tag in tags %}
                            {% if tag in post.tags.all %}
                                {{ tag.label }}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </span>
        {% endif %}         
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the TaggedItem model in my view and add tags to my context dictionary:

```
tags = TaggedItem.objects.all()
```

Then in my template I had to render like this:

```
{% for post_tags in tags %}
           {{ post_tags.tag }
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only make it worse by fetching all tags and adding these to a list. You can do this in the template, so you can simplify your view to:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now


def Blog(request):
    posts = (
        BlogPost.objects.filter(date__lte=Now(), published=True)
        .prefetch_related('tags')
        .order_by('-date')
    )
    blog_paginator = Paginator(posts, per_page=4)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 0)
    page = blog_paginator.get_page(page_number)
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'page': page,
    }
    return render(request, 'mhpapp/blog.html', context)
```

and in the template render this with:

```
{% for post in page.object_list %} 
    <span>
        {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
            {{ tag.label }}
        {% endfor %}
    </span>
{% endfor %}
```

Besides the `ManyToManyField`, you have a `TaggedItem` to store tags in *another* way. This makes it complicated. I would advise getting rid of the `TaggedItem` and store the data in the `ManyToManyField`: a `GenericForeignKey` can not guarantee referential integrity, and makes the ORM less effective. [**`django-taggit`** <sup>[readthedocs]</sup>](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for example also works with a (specialized) ManyToManyField.

That being said, this looks like a perfect match for a [**`ListView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.list.ListView):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now
from django.views.generic import ListView


class BlogListView(ListView):
    queryset = (
        BlogPost.objects.filter(date__lte=Now(), published=True)
        .prefetch_related('tags')
        .order_by('-date')
    )
    paginate_by = 4
    template_name = 'mhpapp/blog.html'
```

---

> **Note**: functions are normally written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, therefore it is
> advisable to rename your function to `blog`, not <s>`Blog`</s>.

Comment: So if a page is fetching something like a blog, a gallery, a photo, etc.... it is classed as a function?

Comment: You're answer isn't rendering the tags, unfortunatley.

Comment: @DavidHenson: it does render the `post` itself?

Comment: Hi, yes the post is rendering, but the tags are not showing up, when i check dev tools, there is just an empty <span> element

Comment: @DavidHenson: what if you render `{{ post.tags }}`, `{{ post.tags.all }}`?

Comment: If i change post.tags.all to post.tags, i get the error: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Comment: @DavidHenson: but only render `{{ post.tags }}`, not alter the `{% for ... %}`. The error however seems to indicate, that there are no tags linked to that `BlogPost`?

Comment: ok, no error but no tags showing. They are definitely added to this particular post in the back end.

Comment: @DavidHenson: but in the `ManyToManyField`? Because you seem to have two relations between the `BlogPost` and the `Tag`, one with the `ManyToManyField`, and one through the `GenericForeignKey`, the two are *not* the same. You thus register tags in *two* (different) ways.

Comment: AH ok, that makes sense. So I do not need the ManyToManyField?

Comment: I figured it out, I will post answer. If you can think of a better way to do it feel free to post as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @DavidHenson: no, I would advise you don't need the `TaggedItem` model: a `GenericForeignKey` can not guarantee referential integrity, and makes the ORM less effective. Django-taggit for example also works with a (specialized) `ManyToManyField`: https://django-tagging.readthedocs.io/